# How to integrate react-dropzone with useFormState?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, react-dom, react-dropzone

I'm building a form using useFormState from the react-dom library. One of its fields involves a file input I implemented with react-dropzone. My current code is:

**Form**

```
export default function Form() {
 const [files, setFiles] = useState<File[]>([]);

 const initialState = { message: "" };
 const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(sendForm, initialState);

  return (
    <form action={dispatch}>
      <DragDrop />
      <FormActions />
      <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**DragDrop element (file input)**

```
export default function DragDrop() {
 const onDrop = useCallback((droppedFiles: File[]) => {
   console.log(droppedFiles);
 }, []);

 const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
   onDrop,
   accept: {
     "application/pdf": [".pdf"],
   },
 });

 return (
   <div {...getRootProps()}>
     <p>Drop or select a file here</p>
     <Button aria-disabled={false}>Select</Button>
     <input {...getInputProps()} name="files" />
   </div>
 );
```

}

**Form action**

```
export async function postFiles(prevState: State, formData: FormData) {
 const files = formData.get("files");

 console.log("files", files);

 //implement files upload

 return {
   message: "Uploaded",
 };
```

}

The issue arises when I submit the form, and the postFiles function is triggered. When attempting to retrieve the 'file' property from the formData to assign it to the 'files' constant, it returns a null value. The constant ends up with a null, suggesting that there might be an issue with recognizing the files property in the form, despite its declaration in the input element.

Could it be that react-dropzone is overriding the 'name' property? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you setting your file that you upload? You have got your `onDrop` function that console logs the onChange value which is a file but it doesn't pass that file to the form at all.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, here is the solution I came up with.

React-dropzone only deals with drag & drop operations, so the dropped files belong to a [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object. On the other hand, files added via an `input[type=file]` are stored in the `FormData` object.

Both use the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) interface, but they are different, so you have to bridge the gap yourself and add the files of the DataTransfer object to the `input.files`.

For convenience, I have created a `ref` to the `form`:

```
const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
```

In the `onDrop` function:

```
const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles: File[], fileRejections: FileRejection[]) => {
    if (acceptedFiles.length === 1) {
        // Add the file to the input[file] element (react-dropzone doesn't do it)
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        dataTransfer.items.add(acceptedFiles[0]);
        if (formRef.current) {
            const input: HTMLInputElement | null = formRef.current.querySelector('input[type=file]');
            if (input) {
                input.files = dataTransfer.files;
            }
        }
    // ...
    }
}
```

Now the dropped file belongs to the form and is accessible in `FormData`.

Hope this helps!